# What language is the song "Fallen Heroes" in Akame ga Kill?

Tags: akame-ga-kill

So just as the title says, what is the language of the song "Fallen Heroes", also known as "Le chant de Roma"? ([YouTube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=igKXRrb5_ts))

I have done a bit of personal research before posting over here and what I came up with is that it is not any of the following languages: Italian, Greek, Spanish, Lithuanian, Roumanian, English, German, Portuguese, Hindi. I don't feel like it should be Japanese nor Chinese, and if it is Latin, then it's sung pretty badly...

I could not find any lyrics, so if someone knows where to find them it would be helpful. Otherwise, I have posted a link for the song in case any native speakers of languages that I have not mentioned above could check whether it is their own language.

My best hypothesis is that it's Roma, although I do not know the language.

Comment: The name "Le chant de Roma" is French, though I can't tell if the lyrics are French. [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/anime/comments/38rjij/anyone_know_the_language_of_this_song_agame_ga/) claims the lyrics are probably foreign-sounding gibberish, which is possible; _Aria_ did this, for example.

Comment: It doesn't sound like French off the top of my head, but my spoken French isn't good enough to say definitively. According to the French language Wikipedia page about the Roma, in French Roma seems to be the masculine plural that they use to refer to themselves, so feasibly the title could translate from French into "The Song of Roma". It's not clear whether or not that would make the song actually be in Romani, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The vocalist on "Le chant de Roma" is Maïa Barouh. After dredging through her various social media accounts, I found [the following exchange](https://www.facebook.com/maiabarouhmaia/posts/1379601805396894) on her Facebook page:

> **Antoine Prt** Maïa Barouh, quelle est la langue utilisée dans ce morceau ? :)
>
> > **Maïa Barouh** Du gromeleu :p une langue inventée

"langue inventée" - that is, an invented language. Straight from the horse's mouth.

(Of course, the piece's lyricist certainly would have taken inspiration from various real languages, but I think it's fair to say that the text of "Le chant de Roma" is not, itself, in any real language.)

Comment: Looks like that Facebook post is no longer available, now. (At least, it's not opening for me.)